# how to debug a single testng test with parameters in intelliJ without using @Optional?

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have following test case that I want to debug in IntelliJ. I don't want to use @Optional("defaultValue") annotation because I want to debug the test with a real value that changes every time I debug. It is not handy to set default values every time I want to run tests.

```
  @Test(parameters = { "param1"})
    public void testExmaple(String param1){
        //do something with param1
    }
```

So, Is there are way to define the test data somewhere in intelliJ so that when I right-click and debug, it should pick the value i.e. param1 ? Or may be there is a testng plugin to do that ?

**NOTE: I don't want to use command-line maven+surefire**

Answer (score 1):

Just configure the `parameters` part of the IntelliJ runner: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-testng.html?origin=old_help#config